# Electron error in child process ( only after bundle for windows )

Tags: node.js, electron

hi im creating a electron app that will execute a script and get result. the app is working fine when i run "npm start".

but when i bundle the app and trying to run the child proccess returns error,

" throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module"

i tried "electron-builder", "electron forge" to build the exe. same error for all.

```
child_process.js:317 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Command failed: node analyze.js "C:\Users\PROGRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\uploaded_2021081110393143598\Support Files"
```

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Programming\Desktop\SupportFile Analyzer\dist\win-unpacked\analyze.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:317:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using LocalWp

If you use special characters in the name of your user on Windows, like tilde or $"#$ (like mine that is jes**ú**s) local cant reach your main folder because local can't understand that characters (hapens with other programs too like Vagrant).

Change the username of your windows account (in deep with the user folder too) it's tricky, and many programs can stop working.

The only solution that I found is create another user in windows with a simple name like: test, without special characters, only to use Local.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).